# Access Control question on ADLS for Azure Synapse Analytics Serverless Pool to connect and query

Tags: serverless, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I have a Azure Analytics Serverless Pool ( where I am the admin)
I    also have got access to ADLS Gen-2 through ACL(Access Control List)    for specific list of folders [ In the below image - all green boxes    represents the access that I have ]

[image]

I am running below SQL statement on Synapse Studio ( Serverless Pool)

SELECT
TOP 100 *
FROM
OPENROWSET(
BULK 'https://SAFINCAL.dfs.core.windows.net/Container-2/Post-Sale/shipments/2021/*.parquet',
FORMAT='PARQUET'
) AS [result]

I am getting below error message

Started executing query at Line 1

File 'https://SAFINCAL.dfs.core.windows.net/Container-2/Post-Sale/shipments/2021/*.parquet' cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process.
Visit this article to learn more about this error
Total execution time: 00:00:12.269

The article points to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand#query-fails-because-file-cannot-be-opened

The solution proposed in the article is get myself "Storage Blob Data Contributor". The question that I have is - if I get myself "Storage Blob Data Contributor" - then I may end up getting access to entire container and that defeats the purpose of ACL access granted at folder level ( green highlighted boxes)

[image]

Is that the right understanding ? If yes - how do I ensure I can still query the data in "shipments" folder from Azure Synapse Analytics Serverless pool without getting myself added as Contributor/Reader for entire container/storage account

Thanks

Comment: Potentially silly question, but is your use of `Container-1` in your `openrowset` a typo?  The rest of the directory suggests you should be specifying `Container-2`.

Comment: yes, it was a typo :) thanks - fixed it

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ACLs you need to have at least "X" permissions on containers as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar about Azure Analytics Serverless Pool, but I think it maybe the same as Azure SQL. This problem usually happens because you don't have rights to access the file.
So I  used to [Create an account SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas?redirectedfrom=MSDN), then use the SAS key to access the files.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for a AD pass through solution here - so that I dont need to create/manage these SAS for every individual user